# WSS 3, two sites on one IIS 6 and Srs

Tags: sharepoint, wss

We are running wss 3 with integrated reporting services. The sharepoint site is running fine and so is reporting services. We're using ntlm authentication.
We added another sharepoint site on the same front end server, in IIS we added another ip address for ports 80 and 443 to function properly. I published the site through the firewalls, it works beautifully, accessible from the internet to both sites, ex. https://xyz.company.com
However Reporting services broke when we added the second site once I canged Alternate access mappings to   It says "Error"
Once I returned the AAM back to http://servername:portnumber reporting services worked again.
However the second sharepoint site is not accessible from the internet like we want it to be.
Any ideas on how to fix this so reporting services doesn't break?

Answer (score 1):

Some what sounds like you need to add a host header for the second site and set the IP address to '(All Unassigned)'. This might take care of the second site not working. It might also fix the other issue too.